# Memory Access Violations When Using SSE Operations

Tags: c++, ubuntu, vector, sse, sse3

I've been trying to re-implement some existing vector and matrix classes to use SSE3 commands, and I seem to be running into these "memory access violation" errors whenever I perform a series of operations on an array of vectors. I'm relatively new to SSE, so I've been starting off simple. Here's the entirety of my vector class:

```
class SSEVector3D
{
public:

   SSEVector3D();
   SSEVector3D(float x, float y, float z);

   SSEVector3D& operator+=(const SSEVector3D& rhs); //< Elementwise Addition

   float x() const;
   float y() const;
   float z() const;

private:

   float m_coords[3] __attribute__ ((aligned (16))); //< The x, y and z coordinates

};
```

So, not a whole lot going on yet, just some constructors, accessors, and one operation. Using my (admittedly limited) knowledge of SSE, I implemented the addition operation as follows:

```
SSEVector3D& SSEVector3D::operator+=(const SSEVector3D& rhs) 
{
   __m128 * pLhs = (__m128 *) m_coords;
   __m128 * pRhs = (__m128 *) rhs.m_coords;

   *pLhs = _mm_add_ps(*pLhs, *pRhs);

   return (*this);
}
```

To speed-test my new vector class against the old one (to see if it's worth re-implementing the whole thing), I created a simple program that generates a random array of SSEVector3D objects and adds them together. Nothing too complicated:

```
SSEVector3D sseSum(0, 0, 0);

for(i=0; i<sseVectors.size(); i++)
{
   sseSum += sseVectors[i];
}

printf("Total: %f %f %f\n", sseSum.x(), sseSum.y(), sseSum.z());
```

The `sseVectors` variable is an std::vector containing elements of type `SSEVector3D`, whose components are all initialized to random numbers between `-1` and `1`.

Here's the issue I'm having. If the size of `sseVectors` is `8,191` or less (a number I arrived at through a lot of trial and error), this runs fine. If the size is `8,192` or more, I get this error when I try to run it:

> signal: SIGSEGV, si_code: 0 (memory access violation at address: 0x00000080)

However, if I comment out that print statement at the end, I get no error even if `sseVectors` has a size of 8,192 or more.

Is there something wrong with the way I've written this vector class? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 with GCC version 4.6

Comment: See: [How is a vector's data aligned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456236/how-is-a-vectors-data-aligned) (Also, +1 for a nicely written first question.)

Comment: You're getting segfaults because STL containers don't align for SSE. The weirdness happening with `8192` is just an artifact in the memory allocator that affects the alignment of the returned pointer.

Comment: I think an important question to consider is how much data is being loaded by the `_mm_add_ps()` routine, and maybe more critical, how much is written back. How does that mesh with the actual size of your array of floats? I think the answer to that will point out at least three issues - wrong computed results, alignment issues, and array overrun...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. I guess this brings up another couple of questions:

Comment: 1) Does this mean that every data structure and class that uses SSEVector3D objects also needs to be aligned properly? As well as every std::vector of Vector3D's? [EDIT: okay, I guess it's not a "couple of" questions, it's just the one!]

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out the rather obvious issue where I was reading from and writing to memory that was outside the boundaries of my float array! I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: I'm surprised that this worked at all. `std::vector` will most likely not align the data correctly. Btw, what is the `sizeof(SSEVector3D)`?

Comment: Accessing address 0x80 looks like the original pointer is wrong. Maybe you are using an offset from NULL?

Comment: The error disappears if the `printf` is commented out because the whole thing is optimized away

Comment: Well, it looks like the sizeof(SSEVector3D) is 16, now that I've fixed m_coords to be of length 4 instead of length 3. I'm still getting the same error though. Is the only solution to write my own allocator and use it wherever I have an STL container of SSEVector 3D objects? Since I'm not using Windows/Visual Studio, it doesn't look like I have the option of using aligned_storage or __declspec(align(16)).

Comment: Unless you're doing this as a learning exercise, don't. Use an established library instead; I recommend Eigen. Wrt. alignment, the eigen manual as a few sections devoted to that at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/

Answer (score 1):

First, and foremost, don't do this

```
__m128 * pLhs = (__m128 *) m_coords;
__m128 * pRhs = (__m128 *) rhs.m_coords;
*pLhs = _mm_add_ps(*pLhs, *pRhs);
```

With SSE, *always* do your loads and stores explicitly via the appropriate intrinsics, *never* by just dereferencing. Instead of storing an array of 3 floats in your class, store a value of type `_m128`. That should make the compiler align instances of your class correctly, without any need for `align` attributes.

Note, however, that this won't work very well with MSVC. MSVC seems to generally be unable to cope with alignment requirements stronger than 8-byte aligned for by-value arguments :-(. The last time I needed to port SSE code to windows, my solution was to use Intel's C++ compiler for the SSE parts instead of MSVC...

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to notice that `__m128` is 16 byte aligned. Use [`_malloc_aligned()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to assure that your float array is correctly aligned, then you can go ahead and cast your float to an array of `__m128`. Make sure also that the number of floats you allocate is divisible by four.