# store __m256i in std::vector yields access violation only in release mode

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, release, avx2

in a quick attampt, I tried to store AVX2-data (type __m256i) in a vector:

```
__m256i values= _mm256_set_epi32(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16);

std::vector< __m256i > vecValues;

for ( int k = 0; k < static_cast< int >(100); k++ )
{
    vecValues.push_back( values);
}
```

Using VS2012, this *works* in debug mode, but give an "Unhandled exception / access violation" when running in release mode.

Can someone explain, why, and how to store the data correctly?

Comment: Maybe your variable isn't aligned correctly?

Comment: And even if you could do this, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @harold I do this sort of thing a lot (as raw arrays, not std::vector) in routines that are entirely designed around the SIMD type.

Answer (score 4):

The `__m256i` type guarantees that a specific alignment will be respected when allocating space for the value on the stack. However, that alignment annotation is ignored<sup>*</sup> when you put them in a `std::vector`. You will need to use a custom allocator that respects the alignment requirements. That will likely involve the use of the `_mm_malloc` intrinsic or calling [`_aligned_malloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx) in MSVC.

`__m256i` requires a 32-byte alignment, because it represents the 256-bit AVX2 registers. By default, MSVC gives you only an 8-byte alignment (for 32-bit builds) or 16-byte alignment (for 64-bit builds), which is insufficient. This is causing the access violation crash when you try to run the build.

[Donny-Dont has shared a Gist](https://gist.github.com/donny-dont/1471329) that provides an example of how you might write a custom alignment-aware allocator for storing SIMD types in an STL container. You should be adapt this to your own purposes. More examples can be found in the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942548/making-stdvector-allocate-aligned-memory).

<sub><sup>*</sup> GCC will emit a compile-time warning for this:

`warning: ignoring attributes on template argument '__m256i {aka __vector(4) long long int}'`

if you use the `-Wignored-attributes` option (which is implied by `-Wall`). I see no such warning in Clang, however.</sub>