# GCC warning - Wignored-attributes for AVX2 typename

Tags: c++, templates, gcc-warning, avx2

I have this code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <immintrin.h>

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
   using SimdType = typename std::conditional_t<std::is_same<T, float>::value, __m256, __m256d>;

};

int main()
{
    typename Foo<float>::SimdType x;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o8o8T3hP5)

When I try to compile it with GCC, I get

```
<source>:6:95: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument '__m256' [-Wignored-attributes]
    6 |    using SimdType = typename std::conditional_t<std::is_same<T, float>::value, __m256, __m256d>;
      |                                                                                               ^
<source>:6:95: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument '__m256d' [-Wignored-attributes]
```

What is this warning? If I use Visual Studio compiler, nothing is shown.

A similar question [Implication of GCC warning: ignoring attributes on template argument (-Wignored-attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676311/implication-of-gcc-warning-ignoring-attributes-on-template-argument-wignored) is regarding alignment and `std::vector`.

In my case, I want to use only type alias. However, I thought that `__m256` and `__m256d` have the same alignment. What is the difference when I write simply

```
__m256 x;
```

and using typename alias. The compiler should see the same thing at the end, no?

I can silence the warning, but I don't like to silence warnings if I am not sure what they mean.

Comment: Is it [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97222) that has the "suspended" status?

Comment: @AdrianMole seems like it. So I can safely ignore the warning, I guess.

Comment: Not sure that you can or should ignore it. Do a check of the alignment of your `Foo` type.

Comment: Hmm. OK, if it's *just* about the alignment attribute, then it [looks ok](https://godbolt.org/z/7n5aMsKEv). But I'm not really much of an expert on GCC and it's implementation details. On MSVC, the __m256 has a 32 bit alignment requirement.

Comment: Does GCC think `__m128` and `__m256` are the same type?  They differ only in `__attribute__((vector_size(16)))` vs. `32`; they're both float vectors with `__attribute__((may_alias))`, just different sizes.  So if it's ignoring all attributes, that would be the concern.  (`alignof(__m256) == 32` in GNU C as well, @AdrianMole, since it's not defined with `__attribute__((aligned(1)))`.)

Comment: @Peter Well, it gives different values for `sizeof(__m256)` and `sizeof(__m128)`.

Comment: ... and it also gets `sizeof(typename Foo<float>::SimdType)` correct (32).

Comment: @AdrianMole: I meant if `std::is_same` thinks they're the same; if so then the warning about ignoring attributes might be something to worry about.  Of course they're not actually the same because of their sizes, and yeah `sizeof(T)` detects that correctly.  You also can't assign one to the other, like `__m128 foo = _mm256_set1_ps(1.23)` won't compile.

Comment: @Peter Doesn't *appear* to be a problem, from [this short example](https://godbolt.org/z/xoecx4cT5).

Comment: So, the outcome seems to be that GCC isn't *actually* ignoring the attributes but just giving spurious warnings *saying that it is ignoring them*.

Comment: Yeah, seems so.  https://godbolt.org/z/4jacKeYdW simplifies to just what I was wondering, `is_same<__m128, __m256>`, both with the standard header version, and checking the non-ifdef version from glibc that uses a specialization that inherits from true for the case of both types being the same vs. a general case of false.  (The actual glibc header uses a builtin `__is_same(_Tp, _Up)` if `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BUILTIN_IS_SAME` is defined, which also gets the right answer.)