# C++ `std::string`-like container with 4-byte aligned buffer

Tags: c++

I need a data structure in C++ that acts like a standard container of bytes but aligns the buffer at a multiple of four bytes.  I'd like to re-use standard library abstractions as much as possible, rather than rolling my own abstraction.

Until now, I had been using `std::string` and `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` for this purpose.  Unfortunately, I've gotten bug reports on the latest Mac OS, where apparently `string::data()` is no longer 4-byte aligned, but rather rather at an address congruent to 1 mod 4.  As soon as I saw this, I realized of course nothing in the spec guarantees strings will be 4-byte aligned.  I could switch over to `vector<char>`, but unfortunately now I'm not sure why this should be 4-byte aligned.  Potentially even with a custom allocator the `vector` implementation could do something strange at the beginning of the buffer it allocates.

My question:  What is a simple way of getting a dynamically-sized container of single-byte objects from the C++ standard library in which the first byte is at a 4-byte aligned address and individual bytes can be accessed through `operator[]`?

Note that this is not the same thing as asking how to ensure that the allocator used by the container returns 4-byte aligned memory.  For example, `std::string` still allocates 4-byte aligned memory (probably 8, actually), it's just that on Mac OS `string::data()` does not point to the start of the allocated buffer.  I don't see anything in the spec that would prevent a `vector<char>` from doing the same thing, even though for now that seems to work.

Comment: Not the simplest to implement, but the simplest to allow reusing the standard library, is to write a custom allocator.

Comment: Write your own allocator that gets an aligned address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making std::vector allocate aligned memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942548/making-stdvector-allocate-aligned-memory)

Comment: @liliscent though subject of that question looks duplicate, author restrict it to custom allocator there. I do not think this is a duplicate as custom allocator is not the only solution here.

Comment: @NathanOliver What basis do you have for arguing that the custom allocator will work?  Couldn't a `vector` implementation allocate memory but skip the first element (which would be one byte in the case of `char`s)?

Comment: @user3188445 AFAIK it has to use the first element otherwise `data` wouldn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver sadly that argument doesn't work, or else you could argue that std::string has to use the first byte of its allocation, which it doesn't.  `data()` just has to return the first element in the array, which might be the first thing returned by the allocator or not.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution is to use `std::vector<uint32_t>` internally, encapsulate that and convert `data()` to `unsigned char *` when you use it.

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately, because I need byte indexed access.  So at that point I might as well just implement my own container.

Comment: @user3188445 that does work indeed, as I said convert pointer, returned by `data()` to `unsigned char *` and you have byte indexed access.

Comment: But if I'm using `std::vector<uint32_t>`, I'm using `std::vector::operator[]`--I can't replace that with something that converts pointers.  Also, `value_type`, etc. will all be wrong.  I would basically need to implement my own container that internally contains a `std::vector<uint32_t>`, at which point I might as well just implement my own container in terms of `malloc`.

Comment: Yes you definitely can write your own container, but I am not sure if writing it properly would be simpler than a thin wrapper over `std::vector<uint32_t>`.  I gave you one of the solutions, it is up to you to decide which one to use.