# C++ - How to safely wrap malloc or emulate with the new operator

Tags: c++, c, new-operator, type-safety, alloc

Is there a commonly accepted-as-safe approach to wrapping `malloc` in a function in C++? What I am attempting to do is allocat arbitrarily sized blocks of memory for holding the output of a function that writes binary values into a fixed size buffer (ie: machine instructions). The approach I am currently using is like so:

```
class voidp {
  void *p;
public:
  voidp (void *pp) : p (pp) {}
  template<class T> operator T *() { return (T *) p; }
};

When converting C to C++, you can define malloc like this:

inline voidp
mymalloc (size_t size)
{
  return malloc (size);
}
#define malloc mymalloc
```

In many cases, it seems like explicit casts to `(void*)` (at least in the case of my compiler) are not allowed, and I must use the template-based approach above.

Is this approach safe, and are there any implications with respect to the "rule of three" (ie: are there any constructors I need to disable or explicitly define/overload)?

Thank you.

**References**

1. *My Rant on C++'s operator new - Punching a Whole in the Type System*, Accessed 2014-09-05, [`<http://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/home/papers/c++-new.html>`](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/home/papers/c++-new.html)
2. *Solve the memory alignment in C interview question that stumped me*, Accessed 2014-09-05, [`<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me)

**Edit**

---

The reason I am doing this is because I'm trying to use something potentially better than just allocating a block of characters via `void* buffer = new char[100]`. To further elaborate, I am writing some lower-level code that, against my recommendations, **must** be written in C++, not pure C. I am also required to have dynamic memory allocation methods that create chunks of memory on the heap that are 16-byte, 32-byte, and 64-byte aligned, like in the example below for 16-byte alignment.

```
{
  void *mem = malloc(1024+15);
  void *ptr = ((uintptr_t)mem+15) & ~ (uintptr_t)0x0F;
  memset_16aligned(ptr, 0, 1024);
  free(mem);
}
```

My application literally creates group of low level machine instructions in blocks which must be 16/32/64 byte aligned (or it will trigger a CPU-level error), and then passes them off to an on-board DSP chip, which runs them as actual instructions, not just input data.

Comment: Why are you usign `malloc` instead of `new`?

Comment: What's the point of this?You aren't writing a memory manager or not taking care of size numbers requested etc

Comment: TL;DR; Something using [placement `new()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new) may be?!?

Comment: maybe store the output of your function in a `std::vector<char>` for arbitrarily sized blocks of memory

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: What's generally accepted is that you should make up your mind whether you're going to write C or C++, *not* trying to continue writing C that's warped enough to be compiled by a C++ compiler (which is what the linked article seems to attempt).

Comment: The author of your article is nostalgic, has not understood the benefits of strong typing, nor the philosophy of C++.  You should really use better sources for your inspiration, such as "Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs": with  smart pointers and some design efforts you could to get rid of need to override malloc() for debugging purpose.

Comment: So you want to go back to C code you must wrap because the code that does exactly that in C++ "can't implicitly cast from `void*`"? C or C++, pick one. These are different languages. Mixing the two should be done only for compatibility purpose IMHO (old libs only in C, etc.)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's not about **where** I want to allocate the memory (well, in the heap anyways), but the exact size, and the ability to cast it to `void*` so it can be used to store arbitrary binary data.

Comment: @Dogbert You're barking up the wrong tree! Using `void*` is the wrong approach. Read more about placement new, and how to use it. If this isn't solving your problems, you're having a XY-problem here, and your design is seriously flawed (which could be suspected using placement new already, besides the rare valid cases).

Comment: So, from the edits above, I now note that I will have instructions that are 16/32/64 bits in width, and they must be "fed" to an external DSP in 16/32/64 BYTE aligned chunks, or it causes a hardware error.

Comment: @Christophe I don't feel the "nostalgic" comment is really appropriate. I've worked with C++ for a while, but mainly with higher level work (application level, we do all our driver, firmware, and OS level code in C and assembler). I've updated the question to be more specific (ie: portable 16-byte alignment requirements, etc). This should justify why I find myself compelled to use `malloc`, and `void*` casts, since I'm writing byte streams of variable bit-widths to it.

Comment: @GWW I've updated the question. I'm using `malloc` instead of `new` because I don't see any portable way of using `new` to force 16-byte alignment.

Comment: @Cratylus As I note in a comment above, I'm technically writing a minimal memory manager, and need to be able to enforce 16-byte alignment in a portable (ie: non-GCC-specific) manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Topic 1:  The old good `void*` ?**

C++ has stronger typing than C. ***It's not a problem, but rather a solution !*** The compiler in such way intercept a lot of nasty issues that would take you hours to find out when debugging.

Simple example.  The folowing code compiles in C.  When I execute I get a core dump.

```
FILE *fp;                     // file 
void *pbuff;                  // pointer to buffeer
pbuff = malloc(BUFSIZ); 
fp=fopen("test.txt", "rw");
fread(fp, BUFSIZ, 1, pbuff);  // ooops !!  Did you notice ?
```

Why ?  I inverted fp and pbuff.  Both are victims of the `void*` to `anything*` and `anything*` to `void*` constructs.  Of course, experimented programmers don't make such mistakes on standard libraries !  But what with the rest ?

With C++ this erroneous code doesn't compile, because converting `void*` pbuff to `FILE*` is recognized as a problem.

**Topic 2:  Is template voidp a safe practice ?**

Well, C++ has classes and inheritence.  And a whole bunch of casts to highlight the weird pointer operations you could (and are still allowed to) do.  Again C++ eases the bug finding.  For example a `reinterpret_cast<>` deserves more care than a more controlled `static_cast<>`

To do safe things, one need to understand C++ object model and use the appropriate tools.    Your `voidp()` is very clever, but it's no an appropriate tool for OOP.

Simple example, first the native way:

```
   struct A { std::string name; A(std::string s) : name(s) {} };
   struct B : A { int x, y;  B(std::string s, int a, int b) : A{ s }, x(a), y(b) {}  };
    ...
    A a{ "Chris" };
    B b{ "Tophe", 30, 40 };
    A *gpa = &a; 
    B *gpb = &b; 
    gpa = gpb;    // yes, works, because a B is an A and compiler knows it. 
    //gpb = gpa;  // No ! you can't without a recast !
```

Now with your `voidp` approach:

```
voidp pa(&a); 
voidp pb(&b);
pb = pa;  // no problem.  
gpb = pa;  // no problem ! Not even a cast to draw attention on potential issue !
```

So you see, ***it's rather unsafe !***  It really hides nasty errors !

**Topic 3:  Is `malloc()` better than `new` ?**

Honnestly, with `malloc()`  you can easily create anything. And it's as easy to create something of the wrong size....    With `new`, you can also do weird things, but it's more difficult to do basic errors.

`new` can call the object constructor. With `malloc()` you need extra steps to do so.

Then, when you have `malloc()` you have `free()`.  `malloc()`/`free()` are excellent for passive data structures that you have in C.  But in C++, when you want get rid of an object properly, you have to destoy is.  So `delete` is really more appropriate .

**Conclusion**

I've read your reference with interest.  It's true, that `new` has limitations.

But I don't share the article's conclusions.  Instead of avoiding `new` and switch back to `malloc()` (again:  it's perfect for C code, but simply not the best fit for C++), it would be a better way to investigate the standard library and for example use `shared_ptr<>` and other smart pointers.  These are much better for avoiding memory leaks, than rewriting one own version of malloc...

***Edit***

The specific use that you make could be done in C++ as well

```
char buffer[1024 + 15];     // allocation  on stack, or char *mem = new char[1024+15]  
char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(((uintptr_t)&buffer + 15) & ~(uintptr_t)0x0F);   // Yes
std::fill_n(ptr, 0, 1024);     // is memset_16aligned() really portable ?  
// nothing if on stack         // or delete[] mem if new was used
```

There exist also the function [`std::align()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/align/?kw=align) that does the calculation you do for ptr.
And there is a placement-new to allocate a C++ object on a fixed address, for example:

```
char* p = new(ptr)char[1024];  // of course you shouldn't delete this one
```

Comment: Would you be able to take a glance at my second edit? I elaborate a bit more on my problem. I need to write binary machine instructions which get passed off to an external chip, and I need to have a portable means of enforcing 16/32/64 byte alignment of the allocated memory. I know how to do this in a portable manner in C via `malloc`/`calloc`, but not with `new`.

Comment: let me have a look - at first sight it would be a candidate for a placement-new.

Comment: That's the thing. I could use placement-new (a concept I'm fairly familiar with), but I don't see any way to force either placement-new to do things like 16-byte alignment without the use of GCC-specific compiler extensions. I could always use static memory allocation tricks (ie: re-casting an array of `double`s to char, or some bizarre semi-portable `struct` manipulation trips), but that might not work either.

Comment: I've added an edit to answer to your specific case.

Comment: `std::align()` looks like what I need, along with the edits made. Thank you!

Comment: For Topic 1, you could use `char * pbuff` and the compiler will catch the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing C++ code.  You should use new and delete.  Writing C style in C++ is generally bad practice, as the C++ compiler will not produce optimal binaries.  If you find yourself doing a lot of type casting with void*, you're probably doing it wrong.

Conversely, use C++11 smart pointers!

Answer (score 0):

The `new` and `delete` are for low level library development.
There are STL containers available for buffer allocation and de-allocation.

In your case, you may try

```
std::vector<unsigned char> myBuffer(MAX_SIZE);
```

Comment: Is there a portable (ie: non-GCC specific) way to force vectors to be 16-byte aligned? Thanks!

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456236/how-is-a-vectors-data-aligned