# C++: How to get the exact object from a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17

I'm working on this code where I want to create a 256-byte aligned vector. In my constructor, I have the following code:

```
BitVector(long bitSize) {
    vector<long long> temp(bitSize, 0LL);

    int size = sizeof(temp);
    
    void* p2 = aligned_alloc(256, size);

    void* p3 = memmove(p2, &temp, size);

    vector<long long>* t = reinterpret_cast<vector<long long>*>(p3);
    cout<<"t address: "<<t<<endl;
    this->bits = *t;
    cout<<"bits address: "<<&bits<<endl;
};
```

I'm not sure why, but the output is coming out like this:

```
t address: 0x55b8623fcf00
bits address: 0x7fff9c7fc6f0
```

I need to get the exact object from the pointer t, but accessing it by * isn't working.

I also tried storing a pointer to a vector in my class, but ran into issues where random values were being placed into the vector, so I've switched it to this implementation.

Is there a way to get the object from the pointer without changing the address?

More details on what I'm trying to do for clarification:

I'm building a Bloom filter, and I've found that storing long long objects is more efficient from memory than storing bits, so I'm changing single bits in each long long when I need to set a bit. However, for all of this memory optimization to be useful, I need my vector (or whatever storage mechanism) to be 256-byte aligned. I've finished implementing the rest of the Bloom filter methods, but I've been struggling on how to accomplish this alignment.

Comment: `sizeof(vector_name);` is almost always not what you want.  A vectors size (via `sizeof`) is a constant and will never change.  `vector_name.size()` will give you the number of elements in the vector.

Comment: Do you want the `vector` structure to be aligned or the data to be aligned?  Sometimes, the `std::vector` is split into two pieces:  the contiguous data and the overhead.

Comment: Looks like you want to align the buffer contained by the `vector`, not the `vector` itself.  If this is the case, look into allocators. What you currently have looks like it could be a timebomb.

Comment: @NathanOliver Because I'm allocating memory, I need to get the size of the vector itself, not the number of elements that it contains.

Comment: See also: `std::bitset`.

Comment: @gigiprab you do understand that `std::vector<int>a (1); sizeof(a);` is the same as  `std::vector<int>b (1000); sizeof(b);`, right? They both just measure `sizeof(std::vector<int>)`

Comment: Do you _need_ to use `std::vector` here?  This might be one of those rare cases where allocating and freeing memory explicitly is justified.  (Wrap it all up in a nice class, of course :)

Comment: UB galore. p3 is not a ptr to a vector<>

Comment: @user17732522 how would I do that instead? I agree that I need the first element aligned because the rest of the elements should be stored consecutively, but I'm not sure how to approach writing that.

Comment: @gigiprab you may want to rethink how you are learning C++.  `memmove` is **not** how to copy a `std::vector`.  `sizeof` will _not_ tell you how much storage is needed to hold the elements of a `std::vector`.  `reinterpret_cast` will _not_ construct a new `std::vector` object.  I suspect that your learning materials are not reliable.

Comment: Sounds like [this might be what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456236/how-is-a-vectors-data-aligned)

Comment: @PaulSanders I just posted an update to the question for more details

Comment: You need to realize that the vector doesn't contain the data, it has a pointer to a separate buffer with the data. It's that buffer that you want to be aligned.

Comment: @MarkRansom I understand now that I don't need to check the address of the vector, but the address of the first value in the vector to check whether it's 256-byte aligned. However, I still don't understand how to make that buffer be aligned.

Comment: @gigiprab Follow the link that Nathan posted.  It looks like that should work for you.,

Comment: One simple solution is to make the vector larger than you need, then simply ignore the unaligned elements at the front and pretend they don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who looks at this, I was able to solve it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456236/how-is-a-vectors-data-aligned), thanks @NathanOliver. My final solution ended up looking like this:

```
unique_ptr<vector<long long>> arr{new(std::align_val_t{256}) vector<long long>(bitSize)};
```